# Writing to a file with a for loop in Python adding a new column

Tags: python, io, ascii

I have data that looks like this:

```
print(data['ra'][0], data['dec'][0])
308.3194375 89.9638467
```

and I very simply (!!) want to write out to a file:

```
f = open('output.dat', 'w')
for ii in range(0, 10):
    f.write(long(ii), data['ra'][ii], data['dec'][ii])
f.close()
```

TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (3 given).

Why is this so hard to do?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nilesh is correct about this specific error, but the broader question seems to be "how do I write data to a csv?". You don't specify what data structure your data is stored in, but it looks a lot like a Pandas dataframe, in which case [`data.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) will make this process much simpler.

If it's not already a dataframe, then you can convert it to one:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ra': data['ra'], 'dec': data['dec']})
df.to_csv('output.dat', sep=' ')
```

If you are using another kind of structure (such as a numpy record array or an AstroPy table), you can find similar functionality specific to those data structures.

Answer (score 2):

you are passing `3` argument in in `write` which is wrong.

```
f = open('output.dat', 'w')
for ii in range(0, 10):
    f.write("%d %d %d" % (long(ii), data['ra'][ii], data['dec'][ii]))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another pair of parenthesis around the write function and it should work.